# Синхронизация приложения с гугл-аккаунтом

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста.

Есть приложение под Android на java, которое уже давно работает, но я хочу чтобы на другом устройстве, с таким же гугл-аккаунтом, передавались настройки приложения, то есть синхронизировались все изменения и не знаю как это сделать.

Перелопатил кажется всё что можно, и с английским у меня не очень, изучаю потихоньку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно сделать множеством разных способов.

Вот вам вариант:

1. Подключаете FireBase либу - она позволит юзеру логиниться через гугл (а также лицокнигу, твиттер, гитХаб, просто мыло) и сохранять к-л данные в FireBase и доставать их оттуда.
2. Реализуете логин через гугл с её помошью.
3. Создайте модель данных для зраннения нужной инфы.
4. Запишите инфу в удалённую БД FireBase-а.
5. При логине проверяйте есть ли инфа в удалённой БД FireBase-а и делайте нужные действия